# JS: Can I increment a var inside a function() that gets called through setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I have a function `change_background()` that I call from `document.onload` through a `setInterval( change_background(), 5000 );` to change the background of my heading every 5sec's.

Where I'm stuck in writing my function is:
How can I increment my `num` var every time its called?

```
function change_background(){

  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('top');
  element[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url( "media/image' + num + '.jpg" )';

 //when num gets greater than the amount of images
 if( num > 2 ){
   num = 0;
 }

}//end change_background()
```

I'm just messing around trying to achieve this effect. Is this even possible the way I'm doing it, am I going the wrong way about it?

Comment: as a note your code: `setInterval( change_background(), 5000 );` should be `setInterval( change_background, 5000 );` as you want `setInterval` to invoke your function `change_background` every X milliseconds.

Comment: Might be an idea to try and get the images cached as well prior to changing - also reading up on js variable scoping may be beneficial - http://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/5302749 has some great info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var num = 0; // declaration
function change_background(){

  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('top');
  element[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url( "media/image' + num + '.jpg" )';
  num++;
  //when num gets greater than the amount of images
  if( num > 2 ){
    num = 0;
  }

}//end change_background()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It is possible. and you can have this to increment your num.

```
  element[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url( "media/image' + (num++) + '.jpg" )';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can, but that variable should be in the same context than setInterval, something like this:

```
b = {a :1}; setTimeout(function(){ b.a++; console.log(b)}, 1000)
```

if you want to call a function, then num need to be global that way the function will be available to access the variable.

This will fail as `incrementB` cannot access the variable `b`:

```
function incrementB() { return b++; } 
function someFunc() { var b = 3; } 
setInterval( incrementB, 500 );
```

This will work because b is global (but try to avoid this):

```
var b = 0;
function incrementB() { return b++; } 
function setValueToB() { b = 3; } 
setInterval( incrementB, 500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my attempt as I like to avoid global variables. This keeps the counter `num` in a closure which is accessible to the function returned by `change_background`.

```
function change_background(){
  let num = 0;

  return function() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('top');
    element[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url( "media/image' + num + '.jpg" )';

    num += 1; // or num++ or whatever sauce you like

    //when num gets greater than the amount of images
    if( num > 2 ){
      num = 0;
    }
  }
}

setInterval(change_background(), 5000);
```